# How to set line width as zero for one line in google line chart

Tags: graph, charts, linechart

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
        'modules':[{
          'name':'visualization',
          'version':'1',
          'packages':['corechart']
        }]
      }"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In above example how to set line width=0 for Expenses.so that I can see only dots for expenses line. Actually I need to implement in project.
In project for each sub I created a line graph and in each graph one line for student marks in that subject and another line contains highest marks in that subject for each exam.Highest mark in subject in not belong to only one student so I d'not want show it line.
Thank you for any help in this.

I have one working Example but it working when user click legend text.I want it work on page load.
     
        
            https://www.google.com/jsapi'>

```
        <script>
        function updateTable() {

        // quick data - cleaned up for this example real data sources
        data = new Array();
        data[0] = new Array();
        data[0][0] = "DOE";
        data[0][1] = "Maths";
        data[0][2] = "Highest Marks";

        data[1] = new Array();
        data[1][0] = 01-01-13;
        data[1][1] = 85;
        data[1][2] = 99;

        data[2] = new Array();
        data[2][0] = 02-01-13;
        data[2][1] = 95;
        data[2][2] = 97;

        data[3] = new Array();
        data[3][0] = 03-01-13;
        data[3][1] = 96;
        data[3][2] = 98;

        var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

        var options = {
          // title: 'kala',
          hAxis: {title: 'Days',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}}
          ,vAxis: {minValue: 0}
          ,height: 300
          ,width: 600
          ,chartArea: {left: 60}
          ,pointSize: 5              
          ,lineWidth: 2
          ,series: {0:{color: 'black', areaOpacity: 0.0, lineWidth: 2}
          ,1:{color: 'red', areaOpacity: 0.0, lineWidth: 2}
          }
            };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('my_chart'));
        chart.draw(gdata, options);

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 
            'select', 
            (function (x) { return function () { AreaSelectHander(chart, gdata, options)}})(1));

            }

        function AreaSelectHander(chart, gdata, options) {

        var selection = chart.getSelection();       
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(gdata);
        console.log(options);


        i = selection[0].column - 1;


        if (options.series[i].lineWidth == 0) {
            options.series[i].lineWidth = 2;
            options.series[i].areaOpacity = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            options.series[i].lineWidth = 0;
            options.series[i].areaOpacity = 0.0;            
        }

        chart.draw(gdata, options);
        }
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table', 'corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(updateTable);
        </script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id='my_chart'></div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Working Solution
    
        
        https://www.google.com/jsapi'>

```
        <script>
        function updateTable() {

        // quick data - cleaned up for this example real data sources
        data = new Array();
        data[0] = new Array();
        data[0][0] = "DOE";
        data[0][1] = "Maths";
        data[0][2] = "Highest Marks";

        data[1] = new Array();
        data[1][0] = 01-01-13;
        data[1][1] = 85;
        data[1][2] = 99;

        data[2] = new Array();
        data[2][0] = 02-01-13;
        data[2][1] = 95;
        data[2][2] = 97;

        data[3] = new Array();
        data[3][0] = 03-01-13;
        data[3][1] = 96;
        data[3][2] = 98;

        var gdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);

        var options = {
          // title: 'kala',
          hAxis: {title: 'Days',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}}
          ,vAxis: {minValue: 0}
          ,height: 300
          ,width: 600
          ,chartArea: {left: 60}
          ,pointSize: 5              
          ,lineWidth: 2
          ,series: {0:{color: 'black', areaOpacity: 0.0, lineWidth: 2}
          ,1:{color: 'red', areaOpacity: 0.0, lineWidth: 2}
          }
            };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('my_chart'));
        options.series[1].lineWidth = 0;
        options.series[1].areaOpacity = 0.0;    
        chart.draw(gdata, options);

        }
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table', 'corechart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(updateTable);
        </script>

        </head>

        <body>
            <div id='my_chart'></div>
        </body>
</html>
```